# How can I list which users can login without key auth?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root, authentication, key-authentication

I have recently been charged with a large amount of Ubuntu servers that are exclusively accessed via private/public SSH authentication.

There is no information regarding how these servers were configured initially, and root passwords are unknown for 90% of these boxes.

For DR purposes, we need to have console login available.

I decided I wanted a list which users had the ability to login without pub/priv authentication, and I realized I had no quick method to do this in my databanks.

Do you?

Thanks!